# Going back to the app in Ionic framework after open the link

Tags: android, facebook, ionic-framework

I can open a link on ionic framework app in browser. But I can't go back to app after press back button. How can I do that? And also is it be able to open in facebook app automatically when click on a facebook page link?

Here is my try:

```
<a class="link" href="#" ng-click="openLink('http://webadres.com')">The Web Site</a>
```

and the function:

```
$scope.openLink=function(url){
  window.open(url,'_system');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is can be done with cordova InAppBrowser plugin, using the same code above.

You can install this plugin as told in this page: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html